# how to start selenium-server standalone with config file

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid, selenium-server

I'm trying to start `selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0` in standalone role using a JSON config file, but I couldn't figure out the right command
I'm using additional servlets for the hub and for the node, but I want to start the server using a single command
so instead of starting:
`java -cp my_proxy.jar:selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0.jar org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3  -role hub -hubConfig configHub.json`
and
`java -cp my_proxy.jar:selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0.jar org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3 -role node -nodeConfig configNode.json`
I want to do something like this if it is possible:
`java -cp my_proxy.jar:selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0.jar org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3  -role standalone -hubConfig configHub.json -nodeConfig configNode.json`